# authoryear-style citation call-out with hand-built thebibliography environment

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

Suppose, I am using the simple `thebibliography` environment in my LatTeX document.

For example -

> ```
> I am citing\cite(reference1) this. 
> \begin{thebibliography}{99}
> \bibitem{reference1} Michel Goossens, Franck Mittelbach, and Alexander
>          Samarin, The LATEX Companion, Addison Wesley, 1998
> \end{thebibliography}
> ```

The output is like -

```
I am citing[1] this.
```

But I want the output like -

```
I am citing[Goossens et al., 1998] this.
```

It is similar to *apalike* like style format as stated in [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibtex_bibliography_styles). The difference is that I don't want to use BibTeX to create the bibliography.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your objective, you need to (a) load the `natbib` package with the option `square`, (b) use `\citep` rather than `\cite` instructions, and (c) provide an explicit optional argument for each and every `\bibitem` entry. The optional argument *must* consist of (i) the author string, exactly as you wish it to appear in the body of the citation call-out -- here: "Goossens et~al." and (ii) the publication year in parentheses -- here: "(1994)".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\begin{document}

I am citing\citep{reference1} this. 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Goossens et~al.(1994)]{reference1} Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and 
         Alexander Samarin, The \LaTeX{} Companion, Addison Wesley, 1994.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.